# TextView selection after EditText has been focused

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a TextView which has text selectable.

```
        <TextView
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/reading_left_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/reading_right_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/reading_content_title_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/reading_text_size"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.8"
            android:id="@+id/text_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In the same fragment i have an EditText.

Once I focus into the editText, I am not able to select text on the TextView any more. However, if I minimize the app and reopen, I am able to again select the text on the TextView.

```
                <EditText
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:hint="@string/type_here"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#00000000"
                    android:id="@+id/input_comment"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorCommentsText"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I have tried `textview.invalidate()`, `textview.requestFocus()` neither seems to work.

EDIT: Forgot to mention I have done `edittext.clearFocus()` before trying to select text from textView.

Comment: Try to add `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in your textview.

Comment: Tried that, still facing the same issue.